# Should I use "narrations" or "narratives"?

Tags: word-usage, differences

At work I keep seeing the term *narrations* as opposed to *narratives* and I'm trying to understand if this is common across the English speaking world or if this is just a term in the US.

Comment: These are different. A *narration* is the act of narrating, while a *narrative* is basically a story.

Comment: Please be sure to present the results of your own research when writing a question (for example, dictionary searches). One of the downvote reasons is "shows lack of research".

Answer (score 2):

I've always understood the distinction between *narration* and *narrative* in much the same way that Jonathon Spirit describes it in his brief comment above. However, Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary (2003) provides overlapping definitions that present readers with far muddier waters. For the noun *narration*, the Eleventh Collegiate has this:

> **narration** *n* (15c) **1 :** the act or process or an instance of narrating **2 :** STORY, NARRATIVE

And for the noun *narrative*, it has this:

> **narrative** *n* (1567) **1 :** something that is narrated : STORY, ACCOUNT **2 :** the art or practice of narration **3 :** the representation in art of an event or story; *also :* an example of such a representation

A quick comparison of the two sets of definitions suggests that *narration* definition 1 and *narrative* definition 2 are extremely similar, and that *narration* definition 2 and *narrative* definition 1 are virtually identical. That leaves *narrative* definition 3 as the only meaning of either term that doesn't have a closely corresponding meaning attached to the other term. But even that definition isn't as clear-cut a point of differentiation as you might think.

As recently as the Sixth Collegiate (1958), *narration* had three definitions and *narrative* only two. For *narration*:

> **narration** *n* **1.** A narrating. **2.** A narrative; a story. **3.** Discourse, or an example of it, designed to represent a connected succession of happenings, esp., such discourse involving plot, setting, and characterization.

For *narrative*:

> **narrative** *n* **1.** That which is narrated; an account; a tale; a story. **2.** Act, art, or practice of narrating; as, a master of *narrative*.

*Narration* 1 is again paired with *narrative* 2, and *narration* 2 with *narrative* 1;but this time the lengthy definition involving representation of a story in discourse or art is assigned to *narration* instead of to *narrative*.

The Seventh Collegiate (1965) drops the third definition altogether, leaving the two terms with their two pairs of essentially interchangeable definitions. The third definition of *narrative*, given in the second block quote above the Eleventh Collegiate, debuts (with identical wording) in the Ninth Collegiate (1989).

All of which is by way of saying that I can see why you might find it difficult to distinguish between the two terms. Still, historically, dictionaries and other resources have attempted to differentiate between them. The Fifth Collegiate (1941), for example, includes this usage note on the related words *narrative*, *narration*, *account*, and *recital*:

> **Narrative** is commonly applied to that which is narrated; **narration**, to the act or process of narrating. **Account** is less formal than *narrative*; **recital** commonly implies a somewhat less detailed relation.

S. I. Hayakawa, *Choose the Right Word* (1968) is so confident that the "account, tale, story" meaning belongs to *narrative* and not to *narration* that it completely omits *narration* from consideration in a discussion of the group of words *narrative*, *anecdote*, *legend*, *myth*, *saga*, *story*, *tale*, and *yarn*.

James Fernald, *English Synonyms, Antonyms, and Prepositions* (1896) seems far less disposed to distinguish between the two terms:

> An *anecdote* tells briefly some *incident*, assumed to be fact. If it passes close limits of brevity, it ceases to be an *anecdote*, and becomes a *narrative* or *narration*.

But elsewhere, this book elaborates on the precise meaning of *narrative* without mentioning *narration* at all:

> A *narrative* is a somewhat extended and embellished *account* of events in order of time, ordinarily with a view to please or entertain.

Despite the extensive overlap in meaning between the two terms, I suspect that many people consistently use *narrative* and *narration* to refer to different things—namely, *narrative* to refer to "story or account" and *narration* to refer to "the act of narrating" (that is, "telling a story").